# How to provide new line in the headertoolbar?

Tags: sapui5

I am creating a table using `sap.m.table`. For that I need to create a `headertoolbar`.

My question is, how would I create elements in separate lines(one item per line) by using the `aggregation headertoolbar` of `sap.m.table`?

Answer (score 0):

> Solution in js view, Please adjust the width according to your needs

```
headerToolbar: [
  new sap.m.Toolbar({
    height: 'auto',
    content: [
      new sap.m.VBox({
        items: [
          new sap.m.HBox({
            items: [
              new sap.m.SearchField({
                placeholder: "search"
              })
            ]
          }),
          new sap.m.HBox({
            items: [
              new sap.m.Button({
                text: "One"
              }),
              new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Two"
              }),
              new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Three"
              }),
              new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Four"
              }),
              new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Five"
              })
            ]
          })
        ]
      })
    ]
  })
]
```

> Solution in XML View

```
<headerToolbar>
  <Toolbar height='auto'>
    <content>
      <VBox>
        <Text text="Text one" />
        <Text text="Text two" />
        <Text text="Text three" />
        <Text text="Text four" />
      </VBox>
    </content>
  </Toolbar>
</headerToolbar>
```

Comment: plz provide me the solution in Javascript :) i have  5 buttons in my header tool bar,search is one among them .I would like to place the search button in the secon line, how would i achieve it?